# How to anchor the viewport to the bottom of the div that slides up?

Tags: html, css

Simplifying the issue...

I've got a div right above the footer.
After 2 secs I want the div to reveal its content.
Div contains some dinamically loaded things that most likely would make it over 100vh in height.
I want the viewport to stay at the bottom of the page (follow the footer) but it goes up following the div.

```css
.irrelevant-top-of-the-page{
height: 50vh;
width: 100%;
background: yellow;
}

.the-div{
max-height: 0;
width: 100%;
background: blue;
overflow: hidden;
animation: slideIt 2s 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideIt {
100% {
  max-height:150vh;
}

}

.footer{
height: 20vh;
width: 100%;
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="irrelevant-top-of-the-page"></div>
  <div class="the-div">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to `position: absolute` and adjust the `top` position as you increase the `height` of the container.

Comment: Well I don't know the `height` of the container.